# Properties of sum Compact Sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that if A and B are two compact subsets of R, then A + B is compact. Where
A + B = {x + y; x ∈ A, , y ∈ B}.

Answer (score 1):

$f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R $ given by addition is continuous, and so $f (A\times B) $ is compact.